# Login con 3 tipos de usuarios en diferentes tablas c# winform

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, windows-forms, login

Sucede que tengo una bd en sql que tiene 3 tablas: administrador, maestro y estudiante. Estoy haciendo un login con id y contraseña  quiero que cuando ingrese le muestre un form diferente dependiendo el tipo de usuario.

¿Cuál sería la manera de hacerlo?, solo he encontrado la solución si pongo todos los usuarios en una misma tabla, pero en este caso no puedo hacer eso, porque por no tienen el mismo número de campos

Comment: Deberias tener una tabla Usuario y esta que tenga un campo idTipoUsuario, según el tipo te envia al formulario que quieras.

Comment: Por otro lado, deberias tener los campos que sean comunes en otra tabla e ir separando las entidades lo mejor que puedas reutilizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternativa 1)**
La cuestión con tu pregunta es que la manera correcta, como tu lo mencionas, es tener una misma tabla donde estén todos los usuarios, dicha tabla debe poseer un campo que distinga que tipo de usuario es cada uno, puede ser un texto plano, pero es preferible tener una tabla `tipo_usuario` que este relacionada a `usuario`.

Ahora bien, mencionas que no puedes porque tienen campos distintos, esto es un tema de bases de datos y formas de normalización (te recomiendo leas más del tema, es muy útil).

Para decirlo de la manera corta, debes identificar los campos comunes entre tus 3 tipos de usuarios, siempre los habra, `nombre`, `apellido`, `telefono`, `email`, `clave`. posteriormente, puedes crear otra tabla llamada por ejemplo `maestro`, que este relacionada con el `usuario`, dentro de dicha tabla tendrás los campos específicos para el usuario de tipo `maestro`. Y de la misma manera se replica para `administrador` y `estudiante`.

Si tienes dudas sobre como hacer el `INSERT` de la estructura que te planteo dime y te explico en los comentarios de la respuesta.

**Alternativa 2)**
Si sigues queriendo trabajar con las 3 tablas por separado, te recomiendo que lo hagas por un email, o nombre de usuario (debe ser único las 3 tablas) y la clave, ya que si lo realizas por la id y la clave, si se repetirá entre las 3 tablas y no lograras saber a que usuario estas buscando, si lo haces de esta manera, debes buscar el usuario en las 3 tablas, y cuando lo encuentres verificar si la clave que ingresa el usuario coincide con la que esta almacenada y listo.

Comment: ¿Me podrías explicar sobre el insert de la alternativa 1?

Comment: Si claro! Te cuento, yo los llamo "Insert anidado" no se si ese es el nombre comun, consiste en realizar un insert (el que necesita la relacion), despues del primer insert (del que necesitamos la ID), lo que tienes que hacer es Insertar en usuario, los campos que le corresponden, obtener la id del ultimo registro insertado (con C#) y cuando tienes esa ID, ya puedes insertar la información faltante en la tabla que coresponde.

Comment: En la vista del usuario, debes cambiar el estado de Visible de los inputs específicos para cada tipo de usuario, este estado de Visible cambiara cuando el combobox que posee los tipos de usuario cambie su valor (es un evento), sera un if que verificara que valor tiene, y dependiendo de eso, pone invisible o visible los correspondientes inputs

Comment: ¿Podrías escribir un ejemplo?, por favor